# Displaying Saved Bitmaps in Android (LinearLayout)

Tags: android

I have 2 bitmaps that I saved with `view.getDrawingCache();` called `firstBitmap` and `secondBitmap`. They were saved from initial drawings made by the user. Now I want to display them. My issue is that only the first picture is displayed by itself (I want both to be shown at the same time). I know that the bitmaps are correct because if I remove `layout.addView(pic1)`, I can see the second image by itself clearly. layout is a `LinearLayout`.

My suspicion is that the size is an issue but I believe that by default views that are added to the layout have fill parent so this should still result in 2 images not one. I have tried dynamically changing the width and size with `LayoutParams` but this makes the image disappear entirely. I am open to any suggestions.

```
    ImageView pic1 = new ImageView(this);
    pic1.setImageBitmap(firstBitmap);
    layout.addView(pic1);

    ImageView pic2 = new ImageView(this);
    pic2.setImageBitmap(secondBitmap);
    layout.addView(pic2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to distribute the weight in your linear layout so that both bitmaps will be visible.

you could use the below code to do that.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, weight);

layout.addView(pic1, params);
layout.addView(pic2, params);
```